# How reback write more better instead of .css()?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
$(".box1").click(function() {
  $(this).animate({
      left: "300"
    }, 1000)
    .fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $(this).css("left", "0px").show()
    })
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 300px;
}

.box1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 123, 123);
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="box1"><a>box1</a></div>
```

this is box move and reback code.

but reback use .css() write not easy read let people understand.

How reback write more better instead of .css() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all the animation styling is done by inline style, you can remove the `style` attribute to reset the original style from the CSS class.

```js
$(".box1").click(function() {
  $(this).animate({
      left: "300"
    }, 1000)
    .fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $(this).removeAttr("style");
    })
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 123, 123);
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="box1"><a>box1</a></div>
```